# Mysql count statement and group

Tags: mysql, join, count, union

I have a following table:

```
id  user type   
11   4    1         
12   4    1         
13   4    1         
14   5    2
```

Then i need count and order the user and type like this:

```
user type1 type2
4      3    0
5      0    1
```

the sql statement that i made just result this:

```
user type1 type2
4      3    1
5      3    1
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: what have you achieved so far, any code?

Comment: Is user 4 always type 1?

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
select user, sum(if(type=1,1,0)) as type1, sum(if(type=2,1,0)) as type2 from table_name group by user
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something similar to this this:

```
SELECT id, user, type, COUNT(type) as count 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY user
```

And seeing some code would be beneficial.